# Is using <footer> inside <form> semantically fine?

Tags: html, semantics, footer

I've been looking around to see if you can use footer like this:

```
<form>
   <input />
   <input />
  <footer>
   <input />
  </footer>
</form>
```

The way I see it, its meets the spec:

> the footer element represents a footer for the section it applies to

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/footer.html

> The footer element represents the footer for the section it applies
>   to.
>
> **Permitted contents**
> Flow content

According to http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/terminology.html#flow-content

> **flow content**
> Flow content consists of flow elements intermixed with
>   normal character data

According to http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow

> **7.1. Flow elements**
> phrasing elements or a or p or hr or pre or ul or ol or dl or div or h1 or h2 or h3 or h4 or h5 or h6 or hgroup or
>   address or blockquote or ins or del or object or map or noscript or
>   section or nav or article or aside or header or footer or video or
>   audio or figure or table or form or fieldset or menu or canvas or
>   details
>
> **7.3. Phrasing elements**
> a or em or strong or small or mark or abbr or dfn or i or b or s or u or code or var or samp or kbd or sup or sub or
>   q or cite or span or bdo or bdi or br or wbr or ins or del or img or
>   embed or object or iframe or map or area or script or noscript or ruby
>   or video or audio or ***input*** or textarea or select or button or label or
>   output or datalist or keygen or progress or command or canvas or time
>   or meter

Input is a phrasing element, so **yes you can**.

There are many online references where

> Footers usually/should contain information about it’s containing
>   element.
>
> A footer typically contains the author of the document, copyright
>   information, links to terms of use, contact information, etc.

but the spec is more than that.

Comment: I did not understand, can a form have header and footer and main or not?

Comment: This doesn't answer if using `<footer>` inside `<form>` is semantically fine or not.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically-speaking, yes you can do that. As far as I can tell, it's still valid HTML.

Semantically-speaking, yes you can still do that if you have reason to (if it makes sense to do it). It's sort of like the new `<section>` elements in that it's used to identify logical "areas" of your page. I think it's explained pretty well [here](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/header-element.htm):

> These new elements help [web crawlers] see sites more like people.

You can even go as far as to make multiple [footers](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_footer.asp):

> You can have several `<footer>` elements in one document.

Comment: Ah ok cool - that's what I figured ... and I DO have a reason so I think this is good. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The semantics is just that `<footer>` means a footer, leaving it open what a footer is. There is no required or even recommended processing for `<footer>` elements, except that they should by default be rendered as blocks (which does not happen on all current browsers).

So the answer does not matter; it is just someone’s opinion of what a “footer” is.

On the practical side, if you use `<footer>`, old versions of IE won’t let you style it, unless you do a JavaScript trick to introduce it (hoping that JavaScript is enabled).

Thus, there is hardly any good reason to prefer `<footer>` over `<div>` (or, in some cases, over `<p>`) with class or id here.